# Shell : Explode and Save file

Tags: shell, awk, explode

I need some help.

**site.txt**

```
[site1] 

server{ 
root test; 
server_name test.com; 
} 

END 

[site2] 

server{ 
root game; 
server_name game.com; 
} 

END
```

this is the command that i use

```
sudo awk -v RS='END\n' 'NF{f=$1; gsub(/[][]/, "", f); printf "%s", $0 > (f ".txt")}' site.txt
```

The output shows

**site1.txt**

```
[site1] 

server{ 
root test; 
server_name test.com; 
}
```

**site2.txt**

```
[site2] 

server{ 
root game; 
server_name game.com; 
}
```

my objective is to remove **[site1]** and **[site2]** from the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow whitespaces before and after `END` as delimiter to get rid of new lines and also have a call to `sub` function to discard first line from output. You may use this command

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]*END[[:space:]]+' 'NF {
   f = $1;
   gsub(/[][]/, "", f)
   sub(/^[[:space:]]*\[[^]]*\][[:space:]]+/, "")
   print > (f ".txt")
}' site.txt
```

**Output:**

```
cat site.txt
```

```
server{
root test;
server_name test.com;
}
```

```
cat site2.txt
```

```
server{
root game;
server_name game.com;
}
```

**Details:**

- `-v RS='[[:space:]]*END[[:space:]]+'`: sets input record separator to `END` preceded and followed by whitespaces
- `NF{...}`: Execute only for non-empty lines
- `f=$1`: Save `$1` which is `[...]` line in variable `f`
- `gsub(/[][]/, "", f)`: Removes `[` and `]` from variable `f`
- `sub(/^[[:space:]]*\[[^]]*\][[:space:]]+/, "")`: Removes first line from each block
- `print > (f ".txt")`: Redirects a single record to a filename made with value of `f` followed by extension `".txt"`.